# Extract a portion of two-dimensional array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optimization, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn how to deal with two dimensional arrays in Swift. Here is a two-dim array I am working on:

```
var Image = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

If I want to extract only first two rows and first columns (2x2), how would I do that with Swift's range operator (...). I tried the following:

```
let extractedImage = Image[0...1][0...1]
```

It did not work. It rather gave me first two rows and columns were printed fully. How can I deal with this problem without using for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or `image[0...1].map { $0[0...1].flatMap { $0 } }`. :)

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: `$0[0...1]` returns an ArraySlice. Without `flatMap` (like what Kevin offered), it will be an array of ArraySlice. `flatMap` helps return an array. Also, in Swift 5, looks like `flatMap` is deprecated. We should use `compactMap` instead.

Comment: sometimes this method crashes my preview though. any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

`Image[0...1]` returns `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

The second `[0...1]` is applied to that same array `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` which gets the first 2 objects which are still `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`.

What you want to do is apply the range to each of the arrays which you can do using map.

```
let extractedImage = Image[0...1].map({ $0[0...1] })
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question entirely but here's a safer way of getting `[[1, 2], [4, 5]]`

```
var images = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
let result = images.prefix(2).map { Array($0.prefix(2)) }

print(result) // [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```